# Как обойти баг Python c ssl

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl

Если в ssl.MemoryBIO() на сертификат клиент ответил

```
TLSv1.2 Record Layer: Alert (Level: Fatal, Description: Unknown CA)
    Content Type: Alert (21)
    Version: TLS 1.2 (0x0303)
    Length: 2
    Alert Message
```

В питоне вызывается исключение:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 888, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE] unexpected message (_ssl.c:2622)
```

Вместо этого нужен EOF.

Comment: EOF - это когда на том конце закрывают соединение. А когда Fatal Alert, то это в чистом виде исключительная ситуация. Какая у вас версия Пайтона? В гитхаб-мастере в строке 2622 нет никаких исключений, да и для `Unknown CA` есть поддержка, а не `UNEXPECTED_MESSAGE`

Comment: 3.9.2-3 из дебиан bullseye